# Get d3 Extent (Min/Max) from multiple line data array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to find the min/max values from a data array by using extent function in d3. I am having the array in the format (x,y1,y2) now I am able to get the extent of either y1 or y2 but not able to get the extent from both the y1 and y2. I want that my function give me extent from both y1 and y2. Please take a look at my code.

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
data = [{x:1,y1:15,y2:23},{x:2,y1:26,y2:12},{x:3,y1:17,y2:17},{x:4,y1:21,y2:22},];

var yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y1; });
console.log(yExtent);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
data = [{x:1,y1:15,y2:23},{x:2,y1:26,y2:12},{x:3,y1:17,y2:17},{x:4,y1:21,y2:22},];

var yExtent = [d3.max(data,function(d){return Math.max(d.y1, d.y2);}), d3.min(data,function(d){return Math.min(d.y1, d.y2);})];
console.log(yExtent);
</script>
```